# R & W python to Modbus

Tags: python, modbus, plc

Sorry for my bad english
I try to read and write from plc with pyModbusTCP lib in python, it seems to work but i am not able to read or write negative numbers. This is my code :

```
ModBus= ModbusClient()
ModBus.host(ip)
ModBus.port(porta)
ModBus.open()


if ModBus.write_single_register(registrow, -100):
    print("write ok")
else:
    print("write error")


regs = ModBus.read_holding_registers(registror, bloccoda16bit)
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: My guess is the `write_single_register` method is expecting an unsigned value; try adding 65536 to negative values (that is, 2**16) and see if that gives the desired value at the other end?

Comment: ok, now i write and read negative numbers but i can't recognize if they are positive or negative

Comment: The number range will be -32768 to 32767, so any number you read larger than 32767 should have 65536 subtracted from it to give the correct negative number.